# access elements of inner structure in a nested body

Tags: c, structure

Can we not access the elements of inner structure?(which is **dept** in this case).

When i try to initialize the value of dept structure, i get errors mentioned in the last.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
struct employe
{
    char name[10];
    int i;
    struct dept
    {
        char name[10];
        int uniq_num;
    }d;
}e;
int main()
{
strcpy(d.name, "CS");
strcpy(e.d.name, "Computer Science");
printf("The dept name: %s \n", d.name);
printf("Employee dept name: %s \n", e.d.name);
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Errors -

```
"example9.c", line 18: undefined symbol: d
"example9.c", line 18: warning: left operand of "." must be struct/union object
"example9.c", line 18: cannot access member of non-struct/union object
"example9.c", line 20: warning: left operand of "." must be struct/union object
"example9.c", line 20: cannot access member of non-struct/union object
```

Comment: remove the `d.` lines, try with the `e.d.` lines, it should work

Comment: Um. ""Computer Science"" thats a few more than just 9 chars + a nul-char. Or were you intending on invoking undefined behavior when this finally compiles ?

Comment: You cannot access inner elements without using object/pointer of/to structure. just like to access name variable, you have to use e.name, similarly to access d variable, you must have to use e.d

Comment: @Rakesh_Kumar : Thank you. i understood the point. I want to make your point as an answer. Could you please post your comment in the answer section, so that i can select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have (by mistake?) used `d.name` instead of `e.name` in e.g. the first `strcpy` call.

You use the correct syntax to access the nested structure in one `strcpy` and `printf` call, when you do `e.d.name`.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned, You cannot access inner elements without using object/pointer of/to structure. just like to access name variable, you have to use e.name, similarly to access d variable, you must have to use e.d

Answer (score 0):

It's better to define the structures separately:

```
struct dept
{
    char name[10];
    int uniq_num;
};

struct employe
{
    char name[10];
    int i;
    struct dept d;
}e;
```

and then you can access the d members of e structure with e.d.name, e.d.uniq_num.